# Blin Phong BRDF in an unusual coordinate system

Tags: raytracing, brdf

a happy New Year to everybody! But, a new year means a new question: In my problem, a mirror is placed in a vertical position, i.e. along the z-axis.The x- and y-axis are perpendicular to this axis. The hemisphere in question is -1 < z < 1, meaning 0 <= theta <= PI. and the azimuthal angle phi is defined by -Pi/2 <= phi <= PI/2. Using a pure diffuse reflection, one can get a random phi as phi = -PI/2+PI*U1 with 0 < U1 < 1 and a random cos(theta) as cos(theta) = 2.*U2-1.

But what are the similar expressions for Phong or Blin Phong BRDF? Looking in to the well known article by Lafortune and Willems, can this be done by sampling phi in the same way
as above and for sampling cos(theta) changing U2 into U2**(1./n+1)?

Thanks for reading and answering (?),

Uwe